# Debugging needs in Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fortran, intel-fortran

I am currently using VS2012 with Intel Visual Fortran. Needless to say I am dissatisfied with the Debugging capabilities for this setup. For my current work I am responsible for updating and modifying large chunks of code from a third party open source console program built in Fortran. While debugging I frequently find myself asking the following questions, but not being able to quickly answer them in my VS2012/Visual Fortran set up:

- What are all the modules in my solution
- What are all the subroutines/functions in each module?
- What variables or types are local to each module?
- What variables or types are local to each function/subroutine?
- Which functions/subroutines/variables/modules are relevant only to current run of the program? I.e which ones are used/not used
- If a particular variable has a scope that spans beyond the lowest level, which subroutines/functions/modules does it belong to?

In summary I need advanced debugging capabilities. In other words to program the debugging of the program itself. I have been looking into CodeBlocks/gdb but am unsure as to whether it can provide this sort of functionality. Does anyone know which direction I need to take in order to fulfill these requirements and answer the above questions? Is this even possible in Fortran programming?

Comment: Do you use all the programs provided with your Intel Fortran? The Inspector? The Inspector, Adviser, vTune and what not?

Comment: Are those external packages that I would have to buy on top of intel visual fortran? I cannot see them installed in my system....

Comment: I probably spend more time debugging than I should. The use of -d-lines may help. It can also be useful to have a character string that you push/pop the routines so you know how you got to where you are at in the code.